# Why is gradle 2.0 so slow?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 2.0.0 with Android Studio and an empty project takes 2 minutes to build. It also creates a 100% CPU usage under Windows 8.1.

Very annoying. Even more annoying that a proper project can take up to 4-5 minutes to build, and it slows everything down.

What could cause this?

Comment: same here.. I always felt "I should'nt have upgraded"

Comment: @breakline kindly share your computer configuration

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have the same problem since 2.0.0-rc3. And sometimes after long build (about 10 minutes)  getting `gc overhead limit exceeded` error.

**UPD:**
Also it uses about 6 GB disk space on SSD.

Have the next configuration:

in app's `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

**UPD 2:**
I think I've found temporary solution - I've turned off `Instant Run` and added next configs:

in the `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

in the `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

in the `studio.vmoptions`:

```
-server
-Xms1G
-Xmx2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=450m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
```

You can find `studio.vmoptions` in:

*Mac OS:*

`~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/`

*Linux:*

`~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions and/or ~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio64.vmoptions`

*Windows:*

`%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio.exe.vmoptions and/or %USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

**UPD 3:** I think, I've found why Android Studio uses so much disk space.

After every `gc overhead limit exceeded` error Android Studio creates a file `java_pid<proccess_id_number_here>.hprof` in your project's root folder.

It has size about `1.2 Gb`, a lot of the `gc overhead limit exceeded` errors `->` a lot of those files. You can just delete them.

**UPD 4:** Builds became much faster, after updating to Android Studio version *2.1* and adding property `maxProcessCount` in the `dexOptions`

```
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "5g"
    }
```

Also, I've increased the maximum heap size for the Gradle in the `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120M
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

And I'm still using modified `studio.vmoptions` file, as I've described above.

Comment: Great difference... Thank you.

Comment: Also found that gradle spawns 4-5 separate JVM's when you set parallell=true. is that bad design or there's a reason behind it? Very weird still.

Comment: Enabling parallel builds with org.gradle.parallel is only useful if your project has multiple modules. You might, for example, have an Android app, a Java library, an Android project library, and an Android Wear module in the same project. When you enable parallel builds, some of the modules can be built at the same time, making use of all the cores in your machine.

Link: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/

Comment: Is there any point in setting maxProcessCount by yourself? It is set to 4 as default according to this site: https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DexOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

In .gradle Folder create a file named gradle.properties and add below lines in that File and Restart your studio once:

org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true